# Line plot with data points in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using `pandas` I can easily make a line plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline # to use it in jupyter notebooks

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), 
        index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=50), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()
df.plot();
```

[image]

But I can't figure out how to also plot the data as points over the lines, as in this example:

[image]

[This matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) seems to suggest the direction, but I can't find how to do it using pandas plotting capabilities. And I am specially interested in learning how to do it with pandas because I am always working with dataframes.

Any clues?

Comment: Please check the editing in my answer, it might be really helpful if you are struggling with setting the correct points to certain dates.

Comment: Excellent, @ViníciusAguiar, very nice tip.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use the `style` kwarg to the [`df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) command. From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

> style : list or dict
>
> matplotlib line style per column

So, you could either just set one linestyle for all the lines, or a different one for each line.

e.g. this does something similar to what you asked for:

```
df.plot(style='.-')
```

[image]

To define a different marker and linestyle for each line, you can use a list:

```
df.plot(style=['+-','o-','.--','s:'])
```

[image]

You can also pass the [`markevery`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markevery) kwarg onto `matplotlib`'s plot command, to only draw markers at a given interval

```
df.plot(style='.-', markevery=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to make these dots snappy, so if you hover over them its like a magnet and you can see the exact value?

Comment: Any chance you know how to add the value (number) above every marker?

Answer (score 24):

You can use `markevery` argument in `df.plot()`, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

df.plot(linestyle='-', markevery=100, marker='o', markerfacecolor='black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

`markevery` would accept a list of specific points(or dates), if that's what you want.

You can also define a function to help finding the correct location:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

dates = ["2001-01-01","2002-01-01","2001-06-01","2001-11-11","2001-09-01"]
def find_loc(df, dates):
    marks = []
    for date in dates:
        marks.append(df.index.get_loc(date))
    return marks


df.plot(linestyle='-', markevery=find_loc(df, dates), marker='o', markerfacecolor='black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I chose the other one just because it explained step by step. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lincolnfrias no problem! I just wanted to make sure you'd notice my edit! =)