# plot dataframe column on one axis and other columns as separate lines on the same plot (in different color)

Tags: pandas, seaborn, line-plot

I have following dataframe.

```
        precision    recall        F1  cutoff
cutoff                                       
0        0.690148  1.000000  0.814610       0
1        0.727498  1.000000  0.839943       1
2        0.769298  0.916667  0.834051       2
3        0.813232  0.916667  0.859741       3
4        0.838062  0.833333  0.833659       4
5        0.881454  0.833333  0.854946       5
6        0.925455  0.750000  0.827202       6
7        0.961111  0.666667  0.786459       7
8        0.971786  0.500000  0.659684       8
9        0.970000  0.166667  0.284000       9
10       0.955000  0.083333  0.152857      10
```

I want to plot cutoff column on x-axis and precision,recall and F1 values as separate lines on the same plot (in different color). How can I do it?

When I am trying to plot the dataframe, it is taking the cutoff column also for plotting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove column before ploting:

```
df.drop('cutoff', axis=1).plot()
```

---

But maybe problem is how is created `index`, maybe help change:

```
df = df.set_index(df['cutoff'])
df.drop('cutoff', axis=1).plot()
```

to:

```
df = df.set_index('cutoff')
df.plot()
```

Comment: Can I show the values as dots also in the above plots?

Comment: @ranusharma - sure, use `.plot(style='.-')`

Comment: @ranusharma - Or similar solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43941245)